# using datetime.utcnow() to set default value in flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Using the code below, I intend to use the datetime.utcnow() value as the default value for that field, but it gives an Attribute Error message that says 'SQLALchemy' object has no attribute 'Datetime'

```
from flask import Flask, flash, render_template, redirect, request, url_for
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///HRS.sqlite3'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'any key'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Treatment(db.Model):
    treatmentDate = db.Column('Date of treatment', db.Datetime, default=datetime.utcnow())
```

Comment: Pass the function as the default, don't call it. And the type is `DateTime`, not `Datetime`.

Comment: I am very new to programming.. so please how do I pass the function as the default

Answer (score 3):

In code what the comments already say:

```
# rest stays the same

class Treatment(db.Model):
    treatmentDate = db.Column('Date of treatment', db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
```

"Passing the function and not calling it" means leaving the brackets () at the end off. Calling the function like you do will actually pass in a datetime object, but what you want is to pass in the function itself as the default to be called in the moment you create a new instance of Treatment.